# What is the correct syntax to refer to a gradient background color in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background

I have a piece of javascript code like this right now.

```
document.getElementById(pos).style.backgroundColor='#800080';
```

I want to refer to the following gradient background color instead of a staic value '#800080' in the code.

```
.myBK {background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000);}
```

What is the correct syntax to do that?

I tried this but it does not work.

```
document.getElementById(pos).style.backgroundColor=.myBK;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: FYI `-moz-linear-gradient` is only supported for the `background-image` property, with `background` being a shortcut to it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-linear-gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add the element to the class *myBK*:

```
document.getElementById(pos).className += " myBK";
```

Or you assign the value to the *background* property:

```
document.getElementById(pos).style.background = "-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ccc, #000)";
```

Comment: > *What’s the reason for the down vote?*  You had `.class += ...` first.

Comment: Hello,
If I can't use -moz-linear-gradient to render a color, what should I use otherwise? Can I use -webkit-gradient?  I don't have an image. I just want to render a gradient  color. I tried this code but it still does not work. Thanks for your help....
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function selectedFocus(pageSize, pos){
  for(var s=1; s&lt;pageSize+1; s++){
  if(pos == s){
   document.getElementById(pos).className += 'myBK';
  }
 }

}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.myBK{
-webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    center bottom,
    color-stop(0.17, rgb(243,95,62))
)
}

Comment: @Java Doe: The space in front of `myBK` in `" myBK"` is important as multiple class names are separated by one or more white space characters.

Comment: hello, Gumbo:
I am sorry to bother you again.
I added a blank space but that still did not help.
Is this because -webkit-gradientis not the right way to go?

Do I need to add a . in front of myBK or I should not need a . there.
myBK{ -webkit-gradient( linear, center bottom, color-stop(0.17, rgb(243,95,62)) ) }

Thanks again.

Comment: @Java Doe: IDs cannot begin with a digit. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id